# Why is variable a (json string) not unmarshalling into struct A?

Tags: json, go, struct

I am probably making a rookie mistake in the code below. Here is the go playground link: https://play.golang.org/p/WS_pPvBHUTH

I am expecting `variable a` (json string) to be unmarshalled into struct of `type A` but somehow it ends up being of `type map[string]interface{}`

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type A struct {
    ParamA string
}

type B struct {
    ParamB string
}

var types = map[string]func() interface{}{
    "ParamA": func() interface{} { return A{} },
    "ParamB": func() interface{} { return B{} },
}

func Unmarshal(data []byte, key string) interface{} {
    //  if bytes.Contains(data, []byte("ParamA")) {
    //      var a A
    //      fmt.Printf("%+T\n", a)
    //      json.Unmarshal(data, &a)
    //      return a
    //  }
    //  var b B
    //  fmt.Printf("%+T\n", b)
    //  json.Unmarshal(data, &b)
    //  return b
    if tmp, ok := types[key]; ok {
        a := tmp()
        fmt.Printf("%+T\n", a)
        fmt.Println(string(data))
        if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &a); err != nil {
            return err
        }
        fmt.Printf("%+T\n", a)
        return a
    }
    return nil
}

func main() {
    a := []byte(`{"ParamA": "aaa"}`)
    b := []byte(`{"ParamB": "bbb"}`)

    resultA := Unmarshal(a, "ParamA")
    resultB := Unmarshal(b, "ParamC")
    fmt.Printf("%+v %+v\n", resultA, resultB)
}
```

Expected Output:

```
main.A
{"ParamA": "aaa"}
main.A // <= this is what I want
{ParamA:aaa} <nil> // <= this is what I want
```

Actual Output:

```
main.A
{"ParamA": "aaa"}
map[string]interface {} // <= but this is what I am getting 
map[ParamA:aaa] <nil> // <= but this is what I am getting
```

Why is variable a (json string) not unmarshalling into struct A? Really stuck here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
a := tmp()
```

`a` is of type `interface{}`. Then you `json.Unmarshal(data,&a)`, and overwrite contents of `a`.

What you really want to do is, first return `&A{}` or `&B{}` from your factory functions, then:

```
a:=tmp()
json.Unmarshal(data,a) // Not &a
```

Comment: Awesome! I finally understood now. Even though the factory functions return the respective types, their underlying return types are `interface{}` so they get overwritten when I unmarshal into them! It makes a lot of sense now. Thank you!!!